# Oversized menu icons?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, globalmenu

Is it possible to fix BlueJ, python and IDLE above normal size icons in the main menu?

[image: menu screenshot "Development"]

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. However, it also does not look like the default XFCE style of rendering the menu. What did you customize exactly? Bugs are off-topic here - so please include *in your question* what exactly you changed in the configuration/appearance.

Comment: Consider yourself lucky. The eclipse icon spans four rows.

Comment: @gertvdijk, I am using style "Adwaita" instead of default "Greybird". Changing back to "Greybird" doesn't fix the icons.

Answer (score 0):

You could install imagemagick and use the convert command to reduce the size. I recommend to try it with a copy of the original file.

1. `sudo apt-get imagemagick`
2. `cp /usr/share/pixmaps/phython3.3.xpm ~/pictures`
3. Use convert. More information about that are on the [imagemagick manual](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php)
4. Copy and rename the original python 3.3.desktop file in `usr/share/applications`
5. Change the path to the new icon file with nano
6. Enjoy you new icon.

Hint. You could convert the file also to png. because there is an [xpm-bug in a unity library](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/990042) that mage some huge icons with xpm files.

Comment: I don't think changing system icons from system packages is very elegant. The Desktop Environment should scale them instead!

Comment: @Josh, I gave up on imagemagick and instead used gimp to resize icons


[screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/hi7P5b3.png)

Comment: This may be easier for some people of course.

Comment: @ gertvddijk Most of them do this and with bmp or png files there is no problem with scaling. Unity has currently a bug related to .xpm files and so I mentioned it.